# 3Proxy и CentOS7 получаю доступ только к локальному подключению. Как настроить подключение для внешнего ip?

Tags: linux, centos7

Почему нет доступа к моему прокси по внешнему ip? Только локально могу подключиться. Что я упускаю?
У меня Raspberry Pi4 и CentOS7

```
[root@localhost ~]# sudo netstat -tuln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State
tcp 0 0 192.168.0.120:8054 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:25 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
tcp 0 0 192.168.0.120:9054 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
tcp6 0 0 :::22 :::* LISTEN
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:68 0.0.0.0:*
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:68 0.0.0.0:*
udp 0 0 127.0.0.1:323 0.0.0.0:*
udp6 0 0 ::1:323 :::*

[root@localhost ~]# sudo iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 5157 packets, 1693K bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination
0 0 ACCEPT tcp -- * * 46.173.153.19 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:8054
0 0 ACCEPT tcp -- * * 46.173.153.19 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:9054

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4940 packets, 1674K bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

[root@localhost ~]# sudo iptables -L INPUT -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 5214 packets, 1701K bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination
0 0 ACCEPT tcp -- * * 46.173.153.19 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:8054
0 0 ACCEPT tcp -- * * 46.173.153.19 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:9054

[root@localhost ~]# ip route
default via 192.168.8.1 dev enp1s0u1u3u7u1 metric 100
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 metric 200
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.120 metric 200
192.168.8.0/24 dev enp1s0u1u3u7u1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.147

Конфиг:

daemon setgid 995 setuid 997 nserver 192.168.8.1 timeouts 1 5 30 60    180 1800 15 60 allow * log /var/log/3proxy/3proxy.log D logformat "-    +_L%t.%. %N.%p %E %U %C:%c %R:%r %O %I %h %T" nscache 65536 auth strong users login:CL:bikzp123 rotate 30 external 192.168.8.147    internal 192.168.0.120 maxconn 35 socks -p9054 proxy -p8054 flush

[root@localhost ~]# sudo tail -f /var/log/3proxy/3proxy.log.2023.12.13
1702475474.025 PROXY.8054 00000 login 192.168.0.105:50645 142.251.39.74:443 1421 6067 0 CONNECT_maps.googleapis.com:443_HTTP/1.1
1702475475.123 PROXY.8054 00000 login 192.168.0.105:50646 142.251.208.174:443 1695 7880 0 CONNECT_analytics.google.com:443_HTTP/1.1
1702475477.150 PROXY.8054 00000 login 192.168.0.105:50653 142.251.173.84:443 2670 12715 0 CONNECT_accounts.google.com:443_HTTP/1.1
1702475477.150 PROXY.8054 00000 login 192.168.0.105:50674 18.244.102.109:443 1338 20055 0 CONNECT_500px.com:443_HTTP/1.1
1702475477.151 PROXY.8054 00000 login 192.168.0.105:50661 18.244.102.39:443 1441 19021 0 CONNECT_www.academia.edu:443_HTTP/1.1
1702475478.156 PROXY.8054 00000 login 192.168.0.105:50677 157.240.224.35:443 1421 25816 0 CONNECT_www.facebook.com:443_HTTP/1.1
1702475479.940 PROXY.8054 00004 - 192.168.0.194:63677 0.0.0.0:0 0 0 0 CONNECT_mozilla.cloudflare-dns.com:443_HTTP/1.1
1702475498.170 PROXY.8054 00000 login 192.168.0.105:50683 34.120.208.123:443 1321 4655 0 CONNECT_incoming.telemetry.mozilla.org:443_HTTP/1.1
1702475533.574 PROXY.8054 00000 login 192.168.0.105:50633 104.26.4.133:443 36869 91874 0 CONNECT_whoer.net:443_HTTP/1.1
1702475545.211 PROXY.8054 00004 - 192.168.0.194:63688 0.0.0.0:0 0 0 0 CONNECT_mozilla.cloudflare-dns.com:443_HTTP/1.1
1702475563.581 PROXY.8054 00000 login 192.168.0.105:50688 34.120.208.123:443 35770 13428 0 CONNECT_incoming.telemetry.mozilla.org:443_HTTP/1.1
```